# What kind of space is described by the metric $ds^2=-\rho^2d\alpha^2+d\rho^2$

Tags: metric-spaces

For an assignment we have to deal with this metric, but it is not really clear to me what kind of space this metric describes. In the assignment it says:
Consider the two-dimensional space-time with the metric $$ds^2=-\rho^2d\alpha^2+d\rho^2$$

Any information about this space would be much appreciated!

Comment: May you tell us the course/context of this problem. A general relativity one?

Comment: Yes, it's a course about general relativity

Comment: If there is in that course something about curvature, you can apply it to the infinitesimal interval you've written. You can ask, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this coordinate change:

$$\begin{cases}
   x=\rho\sinh\alpha\\
   t=\rho\cosh\alpha
\end{cases}$$

And apply it to the metric $\mathrm ds^2=\mathrm dt^2-\mathrm dx^2$

You can interpret $\alpha$ as the velocity parameter and $\rho$ as points at the same interval from origin.

**Added**

It's easy to check that a geodesic in the minkovskian metric $\mathrm ds^2=\mathrm dt^2-\mathrm dx^2$ are straight lines in a $xt$ diagram, so is $at+bx+c=0$. They correspond to a particle following an inertial trajectory, so is, a particle moving a constant speed in a line, or to a photon or a straight ruler moving or at rest (it will be one of the three possibilities depending on the relation between $a$ and $b$, e.g. with $a=b$ the line is the trajectory f a photon). So, in the new coordinates $\rho\,,\alpha$

$$a\rho\cosh\alpha+b\rho\sinh\alpha+c=0$$

$$\rho=\frac{-c}{a\cosh\alpha+b\sinh\alpha}=\frac{-2c}{(a-b)e^{-\alpha}+(a+b)e^\alpha}=$$

$$=\frac{-2ce^\alpha}{a-b+(a+b)e^{2\alpha}}$$

Or

$$\rho=\frac{k_1e^\alpha}{k_2+e^{2\alpha}}$$

$\rho$ and $\alpha$ are named "Rindler coordinates".

Answer (score 0):

Shall use $(r,\theta)$ notation of space-time coordinates instead of $( \rho,\alpha) $ for convenience. Primes with respect to $\theta$.

$$ ds^2 = - (r\, d\theta)^2 +dr^2 \tag1$$

$$ s = \int  \sqrt{ r^{\prime ^2 }-  {r^2 } }\, d \theta\tag2$$

which has functional

$$ F=  \sqrt{ r^{\prime ^2 }-  {r^2 } } \tag3$$

and to find a geodesic for this metric Euler-Lagrange Equation of Calculus of Variations can be employed.

$$ F-   r^{\prime  }\, \frac{\partial F}{\partial r^{\prime  }} = const.\tag4$$

$$\sqrt{...} - r^{\prime  }\cdot r^{\prime  }/\sqrt {...} = const. $$

simplifies to
$$ \frac{r^2}{\sqrt{ r^{\prime ^2 }-  {r^2 } } }= c,\,  say\tag5 $$

Re-arrange getting
$$ \frac{d\,(r/c)}{(r/c) \sqrt{r^2/c^2+1}} = d \theta \tag6$$

which has solution with arbitrary constant $c$ as

$$ \frac{c}{c+ \sqrt{c^2+r^2}}= e^{\theta} \tag7$$

Reduction to its hyperbolic function form is left as an exercise.

$$ r/c= \sqrt{e^{-\theta } (e^{-\theta} -2)} \tag8 $$

Its second order ODE is

$$ r^{\prime \prime }=\frac{ 2 r^{\prime^2} } { r} -r \tag9 $$

Plots for geodesics of the metric for $c=1$ are sketched below, if there is no error.

[image: Metric_Like_Euclid]

Geodesics would not be affected even if the metric is

$$ ds^2 =  (r\, d\theta)^2 - dr^2   \tag{10} $$

To compare ODE with Euclidean metric of positive sign in (1) as straight lines in the plane,

$$ r^{\prime \prime }=\frac{ 2r^{\prime^2} } { r}+r. \tag{11}$$

Comment: The geodesics are too straight lines because the curvature is zero

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by this? In hyperbolic geometry semi-circles are straight. Projectile motion, planetary motion etc. are all straight in obeying a certain metric or a differential condition.Only the Euclidean metric geodesic curvature vanishes for straight lines. The given metric, by virtue of the negative sign is certainly *non-Euclidean*.

Comment: It's not hyperbolic geometry. It's a pseudo euclidean one.

Comment: Whatever, non-euclidean